# Errors in Quadratic Formula Code (Issue with Main and 1 line)

Tags: java, eclipse

I saw some other Quadratic Formula Problems but none seemed to encounter this
essentially there are two issues, one with a block of code that when resolved by inserting a "}" create more problems and the other being the fact that it won't run. I am somewhat new to java and this is my first really complicated set of code, but I am hopefully am just making minor mistakes I just can't see right now.

```
 package package10;

 public class QuadraticFormula 
 {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

    }//Brought in the static void as Eclipse continually insisted this was neccesary. There is a main file I am supposed to be referencing
    //The file name is QuadraticFormulaMain.java and is in the same directory. Is there a way I should be writing this to reference it?

    public static String QuadraticFormula (int A, int B,  int C) 
    {

    }

    int A = 1;
    int B = -7;
    int C = 10;

    //Sets integers to easily testable numbers
    {
        System.out.println("Terry Peters");//Thats my Name
        Object findSolutions;
        System.out.println(findSolutions); 
    } 
    //Runs and Prints out the solution found below

    private static int discriminant (int A, int B, int C)  
    {
        //sets the discriminate with appropriate equation

        return (B * B)-(4*A*C);         
    }

    private static int numberOfSolutions (int A, int B, int C) 
    {
        //The actual numerOfSolutions, checks if the discriminant is positive negative or zero
        if (discriminant (A, B, C) > 0)
            return 2;
        if (discriminant (A, B, C) == 0 )
            return 1;
        if (discriminant (A, B, C) < 0)
            return 0;
     }

    //This performs the find Solutions String mentioned in the beginning
    //For whatever reason All return statements are showing errors, but says Eclipse has a quick fix.
    //This is a lie as all it says is "No Suggestions Avalible"
    private static String findSolutions (int A, int B, int C) 
    {
        if (numberOfSolutions (A, B, C) == 0);

        System.out.println ("There are no solutions");
        return "There are no solutions";

        if (numberOfSolutions (A, B, C) == 1)
            return ("There is one solution and it is" + plusSolution (A, B, C));

        if (numberOfSolutions (A, B, C) == 2)
            return "There are two solutions and they are " + plusSolution (A, B, C) + "and" + minusSolution (A, B, C);

    private static double plusSolution(int A, int B, int C) 
    {
        return ((B * -1) +  Math.sqrt((B * B)-(4*A*C))) / (2 * A);

    }

    private static double minusSolution (int A, int B, int C) 
    {
        return ((B * -1) - Math.sqrt((B * B)-(4*A*C))) / (2* A);

    }
}
```

Comment: Im not even sure where to start.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of problems here:

- Your constructor `QuadraticFormula()` shouldn't return anything
- All of your statements need to be associated with a method (check the curly brackets and make sure all the stuff you want associated with a method is inside them; if there is anything that is NOT in a method, you need to either put it in the constructor, or make a method for it).
- All methods in a normal class need to end with a curly brace, not a semicolon. Methods that end with a semicolon are found in [interfaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_%28Java%29), not normal classes.
- If your code is supposed to execute from a class called `QuadraticFormulaMain.java`, then only that class needs a `main()` method.
- If you want to print an String to the terminal screen, you should use `System.out.println(sampleString)`. If you want to send that information to `QuadraticFormulaMain`, then you should `return sampleString`. You shouldn't need to do both.
- You need to instantiate `QuadraticFormula` in `QuadraticFormulaMain`'s `main()` method. You don't need to reference `QuadraticFormulaMain` in `QuadraticFormula`.

I didn't write the correct code for you because it looks like you need practice. Try fixing your code just by looking at these suggestions and see if you can get it to work. You'll learn a lot more than if you just use somebody else's version.

Comment: Ah I see
Thanks for putting up with some of it. New to java syntax and the practice helped a bit.
Would you have any good links to some project examples that would be good practice for this?

Comment: @user3234240 Hahaha, no problem. I was there not too long ago. [codingBat](http://codingbat.com/) has some really good practice problems and immediate feedback. That's probably your best bet to just work on syntax. If you're still trying to understand objects and the language, the [java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/index.html) are really good. They have lots of tutorials on more specific concepts or packages that you may want to learn about. I was there a lot about a year ago learning the basics of swing.

Answer (score 1):

```
You Have made several misktakes here is running snippet 
 of your code.     

     public class QuadraticFormula 
    {
         public static void main(String[] args) 
         {
       int A = 1;
       int B = -7;
       int C = 10;
       System.out.println("Terry Peters");//Thats my Name

           System.out.println(findSolutions(A,B,C));
         }

        private static int discriminant (int A, int B, int C)  
        {
          //sets the discriminate with appropriate equation

            return (B * B)-(4*A*C);         
        }

       private static int numberOfSolutions (int A, int B, int C) 
       {
          //The actual numerOfSolutions, checks if the discriminant is positive    //negative    or zero
       if (discriminant (A, B, C) > 0)
           return 2;
       if (discriminant (A, B, C) == 0 )
           return 1;
       else
           return 0;

     }

    //This performs the find Solutions String mentioned in the beginning
    //For whatever reason All return statements are showing errors, but says Eclipse has  a  //quick fix.
   //This is a lie as all it says is "No Suggestions Avalible"
   private static String findSolutions (int A, int B, int C) 
   {
       if (numberOfSolutions (A, B, C) == 0)
       {
           System.out.println ("There are no solutions");
           return "There are no solutions";
       }   
       else if (numberOfSolutions (A, B, C) == 1)
       { 
           return ("There is one solution and it is" + plusSolution (A, B, C));
       }
       else
           return "There are two solutions and they are " + plusSolution (A, B, C) + "and"  + minusSolution (A, B, C);
   }   

   private static double plusSolution(int A, int B, int C) 
   {
       return ((B * -1) +  Math.sqrt((B * B)-(4*A*C))) / (2 * A);

   }

   private static double minusSolution (int A, int B, int C) 
   {
       return ((B * -1) - Math.sqrt((B * B)-(4*A*C))) / (2* A);

   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
public class QuadraticFormula {

    int A = 1;
    int B = -7;
    int C = 10;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        QuadraticFormula formula = new QuadraticFormula(2, 8, 4);
        System.out.println(formula.findSolutions());
    }//Brought in the static void as Eclipse continually insisted this was neccesary. There is a main file I am supposed to be referencing
//The file name is QuadraticFormulaMain.java and is in the same directory. Is there a way I should be writing this to reference it?

    public QuadraticFormula(int A, int B, int C) {
        this.A = A;
        this.B = B;
        this.C = C;
    }

//Sets integers to easily testable numbers
//Runs and Prints out the solution found below
    private static int discriminant(int A, int B, int C) {

        //sets the discriminate with appropriate equation
        return (B * B) - (4 * A * C);
    }

    private int numberOfSolutions(int A, int B, int C) {

        //The actual numerOfSolutions, checks if the discriminant is positive negative or zero
        if (discriminant(A, B, C) > 0) {
            return 2;
        } else if (discriminant(A, B, C) == 0) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
//This performs the find Solutions String mentioned in the beginning
//For whatever reason All return statements are showing errors, but says Eclipse has a quick fix.
//This is a lie as all it says is "No Suggestions Avalible"

    private String findSolutions() {

        if (numberOfSolutions(A, B, C) == 1) {
            return ("There is one solution and it is" + plusSolution(A, B, C));
        } else if (numberOfSolutions(A, B, C) == 2) {
            return "There are two solutions and they are " + plusSolution(A, B, C) + "and" + minusSolution(A, B, C);
        } else {
            System.out.println("There are no solutions");
            return "There are no solutions";
        }
    }

    private static double plusSolution(int A, int B, int C) {
        return ((B * -1) + Math.sqrt((B * B) - (4 * A * C))) / (2 * A);

    }

    private static double minusSolution(int A, int B, int C) {
        return ((B * -1) - Math.sqrt((B * B) - (4 * A * C))) / (2 * A);

    }
}
```

- What I did was make a valid construtor `public QuadraticFormula(...)`
- When you pass values to the constructor. It will be the value of the class fields.
- For `findSolutions()`, you don't need an arguments, just use the class fields
- Also I changed some of the `if` statements to `else if` so that you would not get an error for the method saying it need a return value.

Output

```
There are two solutions and they are -0.5857864376269049and-3.414213562373095
```

Comment: This showed a good amount of the errors and some of my own overcomplications (i.e if discriminant isn't positive or zero, its much easier to assume it is negative then creating another statement)

Comment: Though I did notice you changed new formula from 1 -7 and 10 to 2 8 and 4.
unsure why, but plugging it into the original python code the results are the same so its working on multiple numbers as well.